# How to create alternating sign of an "infinite" series in ANSI C using the least amount of system resources?

Tags: c, math, resources

I am working with ANSI C for the first time and I need to sum a series out to an N number of terms.

My background is in physics, not CS, so I instinctively thought to use the old (-1)^N trick, but quickly realized that 1) it didn't work, and 2) ANSI C doesn't have a built in exponentiation operator.

Since I now realize that exponentiation is slow, what is the best way to create an alternating series in for this?  My second thought was checking the parity of N and then using an if statement that gives me either a 1 or -1 to multiply the term by, but I don't know any good methods to check parity on a computer, and I think it would be even slower than exponentiating -1.

Are there better ways to accomplish this that won't heavily tax the CPU?

Comment: you can multiply by (-1) at each loop, or use (N % 2 ? 1:-1) which is an expression returning 1 or -1 depending on the result of N modulo 2, there is also (N & 1 ? 1:-1) the same but with the 'bit and' operator (the value of the last bit of N). and for computing 3^N use pow(3,N)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++

Comment: @user1952009 The term completely chances each iteration, so I can't multiply it like that.

Comment: but you approved an answer where it does...

Comment: Then I guess I just don't understand your comment completely....

Comment: sign = (-1)*sign; and sign = -sign; are not so different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just keep the sign as a separate variable, and negate it as you process each term:

```
int sign = 1;
for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
{
    printf( "%2d\n", sign );
    sign = -sign;
}
```

Comment: This is IMHO the best solution.